# accessing specific elements of dictionary given a list of index

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

l would like to get access to a specific values of my dictionary given their indices.
When l given only one index  or a continuing list of indices [0:30] it works as follow:

```
print(labels.keys()[0])
'IceDancing'
print(labels.keys()[0:3])
['IceDancing', 'IceDancing', 'HighJump']
```

However when l try to access specific indices as follow :

```
indices=[3,4,45,8,56]
labels.keys()[indices]
```

l get the following error

*** TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Thank you for your help

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered in Python 2.7. You should not assume keys are returned in any particular order.

Comment: Yes it is. My purpose here is to get access into a dictionary given a list of indices

Comment: Yep, but if the order is random or non-decipherable, how would indexing ever mean anything?

Comment: l order my dictionary  as follow : for files in res:
    key = files.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
    labels.setdefault(key, []).append(files)

print('sort labels')
for key in labels:
    labels[key].sort()

Comment: That doesn't sort keys within your dictionary. It's not possible to sort a dictionary in 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, dictionaries in Python 2.7 are not ordered. You should not assume any particular or consistent order when you use `dict.keys`.

Nonetheless, what you are requesting is possible with `operator.itemgetter`. Here's a trivial example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {i+10: i for i in range(100)}
idx = [3,4,45,8,56]

print itemgetter(*idx)(d.keys())

# (13, 14, 55, 18, 66)
```